# SQL Statement not working on Oracle JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a statement that could retrieve last month's transaction records from Oracle:

```
select 
    c.CustomerID as id, 
    c.Order_ID as txID, 
    c.Transaction_Date as date1 
from 
    Members a, Verify_Detail b, Verify_Request c 
where 
    a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND 
    b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND 
    b.Order_ID = c.Order_ID AND 
    c.Transaction_Date between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) 
order by 
    c.CustomerID, c.Transaction_Date desc
```

This statement works fine on SQL Developer. But when I use JDBC and Prepared statement to try to fetch my data, it shows me exception `17006: Invalid Column Name, Cause: null` all the time.

I'd like to know what is wrong with my statement that made me unable to execute it on JDBC? Isn't it support to be executed if I could use it on Oracle SQL Developer?

**Update:**
 The code that I use is simple:

```
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDBSrc");
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();

    String sql = "select " + 
                 "c.CustomerID as id, c.Order_ID as txID, c.Transaction_Date as date1 " +
                 "from Members a, Verify_Detail b, Verify_Request c " +
                 "where a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND " +
                 "b.Order_ID = c.Order_ID AND " + 
                 "c.Transaction_Date between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) " +
                 "order by c.CustomerID, c.Transaction_Date desc";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
        out.println("ID: " + rs.getLong("id") + ", txID: " + rs.getString("txID") + ", Date: " + rs.getString("date1"));
    }
}
catch(SQLException e){
    out.println("SQL state: " + e.getSQLState() + ", Code: " + e.getErrorCode() + ", Msg: " + e.getMessage() + ", Cause: " + e.getCause());
}
```

Comment: Ironically, SQL Developer is written in Java so your statement works in JDBC when it runs in SQL Developer.

Comment: Share your code to execute this statement

Comment: Could you show the code to execute this query ? In general, a space is forgot so you have a where clause like `a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID ANDb.CustomerID`

Comment: @AxelH, my thought exactly ;-)

Comment: It is much clearer to use ANSI join syntax rather than the legacy comma join syntax. `FROM Members a INNER JOIN Verify_Detail b ON (a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID) INNER JOIN Verify_Request c ON (...)`

Comment: Code is ok, gives exactly the same SQL statement as above (minus some whitespace)

Comment: Which driver and version is your datasource using?

Comment: @AlexPoole ojdbc6.jar from 12.1.0.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @user6309529: Please check the update to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a guess, but too large for the comments section...

Maybe you connected the lines in a way that two consecutive lines get merged (in my example, the `AND` from one line merges with `b.CustomerID` from the next):

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select "+
    "c.CustomerID as id, "+
    "c.Order_ID as txID, "+
    "c.Transaction_Date as date1 "+
"from "+
    "Members a, Verify_Detail b, Verify_Request c "+
"where "+
    "a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND"  // <=====
    "b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND "+
    "b.Order_ID = c.Order_ID AND "+
    "c.Transaction_Date between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) "+
       "and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) "+
"order by "+
    "c.CustomerID, c.Transaction_Date desc");
```

EDIT: I think the reason is much simpler... it's Oracle turning all Identifiers to uppercase, so try this:

```
String sql = "select " + 
                 "c.CustomerID as \"id\", c.Order_ID as \"txID\", c.Transaction_Date as \"date1\" " +
                 "from Members a, Verify_Detail b, Verify_Request c " +
                 "where a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND " +
                 "b.Order_ID = c.Order_ID AND " + 
                 "c.Transaction_Date between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) " +
                 "order by c.CustomerID, c.Transaction_Date desc";
```

Comment: Too use your words, _my thought exactly_  ;) A specific format for the query is always a good idea, I am used to add a space to every beginning of a new line, this is easier to spot a missing space.

Comment: I'll get `ORA-00933` if I missed an space. sorry but this doesn't solve.

Comment: Are you sure you are working on the same database, using the same user account in both cases (SQL Developer and your program)?

Comment: Yes I did use same account and DB. so this question is really weird since I can't get same result on JDBC.

Comment: 17006 is not an Oracle error; by that I mean I don't think there error is coming from the database.

Comment: @BobC Fsck, you are right... it's probably coming from `rs.get...`

Answer (score 1):

`17006: Invalid Column Name` Is raised if you are trying to get not existing column from result set.

1) Option Add external select and try again `select * from (your_select)`

2) Try to get data with column names. 
`"ID: " + rs.getLong("CustomerID") + ", txID: " + rs.getString("Order_ID") + ", Date: " + rs.getString("Transaction_Date")`

I know there is connection propertie `GET_COLUMN_LABEL_FOR_NAME`. And if is set to false. ResultSet only knows real column_name. But i'm not sure if ojdbc supports it.